# How to bend my screw to the shape of an S

Tags: bezier-curves, image

I want to take my image of a screw (i.e. rectangular almost 1-D) and bend it to the letter S (for "Screw").

Note that I don't only want to distort it, I really want the head to point in the direction and angle of the upper start of the S and the end to point along the end of the S, i.e. along the vector a pencil would move as the end is drawn.

Can anyone help accomplish this?

Comment: Why no subdivide the image, a whole bunch, then rig it with armatures? you can rotate/move the armatures and the image should behave similarly to how you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the images as plane add on. Insert your image plane & browse to your desired image, then sub-divide it up. Add a lattice. Then on your image plane use the lattice modifier, and select your lattice as the reference object inside the modifier. Then manipulate your lattice to have the S-Shape that you desire.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like as good a method as any.

Comment: Is it possible to rotate pieces of the lattice? I'd like the top to be more forward facing.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll modify my answer to include the blend, that way you can see what its made up of. As far as the lattice, go into edit mode like you would a mesh, and select its vertices. Then you can Move/Rotate all you want.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

The blue scaled cube with many loop cuts has Curve Modifier.

Consider

- Curve Modifier

With much more difficulty

- Armature Modifier
- Spline IK Modifier with an armature